# How to declare event property in interface?

Tags: c#, .net, events, interface, c#-7.0

In C# 7.0, is it possible to declare an event property in an in a `interface`, something like:

```
delegate void Del();
interface I
{
    event Del E { add; remove; }
}
```

Similar to properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but you either need to remove `{ add; remove; }`:

```
interface I
{
    event Del E;
}
```

Or expose the delegate as a [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties):

```
interface I
{
     Del E { get; set; }
}
```